# Django REST Framework TypeError: register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'viewset'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Im learning Django REST Framework and Im trying to get to work a simple ViewSet but I keep getting this error on the console when trying to run the server

```
  File "C:\Users\anahu\Projects\guatudu-api\api\api\locations\urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    router.register(r'countries', country_views.CountryViewSet, basename='country')
TypeError: register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'viewset'
```

this is my app's urls.py

```
"""Locations Urls"""

# Django
from django.urls import path, include

# Django Rest Framework
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

# Views
from api.locations.views import countries as country_views

router = DefaultRouter
router.register(r'countries', country_views.CountryViewSet, basename='country')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

And this is my ViewSet

```
"""Countries view"""

# Django REST Framework
from rest_framework import viewsets

# Serializers
from api.locations.serializers import CountryModelSerializer

# Models
from api.locations.models import Country

class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Country viewset"""

    queryset = Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountryModelSerializer
```

and this is my serializer

```
"""Country Serializers"""

#Django Rest Framework
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator

#Model
from api.locations.models import Country

class CountryModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Country Model Serializer"""

    class Meta:
        """Meta class"""
        model = Country
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'image'
        )
```

is pretty basic stuff, but I keep getting that error. All I can imagine is that for some reason Im not getting the ViewSet from on the urls.py correctly? I hope you guys can help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your url:

```
"""Locations Urls"""

# Django
from django.urls import path, include

# Django Rest Framework
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

# Views
from api.locations.views import countries as country_views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'countries', country_views.CountryViewSet, basename='country')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: seems it worked because router = DefaultRouter() (origin is router = DefaultRouter)

Comment: Just add the brackets:  `DefaultRouter` to `DefaultRouter()`

Answer (score 7):

It's a simple error.

```py
router = DefaultRouter
router.register(r'countries', country_views.CountryViewSet, basename='country')
```

change this code to :

```py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'countries', country_views.CountryViewSet, basename='country')
```

`DefaultRouter()` is a function.